# Nonogram solver - Finding all possible row combinations according to its constraints on Python, using backtracking

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I'm currently working on a Nonogram solver on python, and having a problem with calculating all possible row combinations using backtracking.

So, I need a function, `foo`, that receives a row and constraints `foo(row, const)`, and returns the combinations according to the order in the constraints list.

The row contains the elements: 1, 0 or "?".

1 - already colored

0 - not colored

"?" - neutral (can be both colored and not colored)

Few examples of the wanted output:

```
foo([1, 1, "?", 0], [3]) ---> [[1, 1, 1, 0]]

foo(["?", 0, 1, 0, "?", 0], [1,1]) ---> [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

foo([0, 0, "?", 1, 0] , [3]) ---> []
```

Here's my failed attempt:

```
def foo(row, const, options_lst=[]):

if len([const[j] for i in range(len(row)) if row[i:i + const[0]]
       == const[0]*[1] for j in range(len(const))]) >= 1:
    if row not in options_lst:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if row[i] == "?":
                row[i] = 0
        options_lst.append(row)
    print(options_lst)
    return

for i in range(len(row)):
    if row[i] == "?":
        row[i] = 1
        foo(row, const)
```